# SQL Server - How to count number of distinct entries across multiple columns?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table similar to this:

```
FORM_NUM         DOB_1           DOB_2            DOB_3
1                06Jul1973                        20Jan1994
1                06Jul1973       12Mar1980        20Jan1994
2                17Oct1960       12Dec1996        12Dec1996
2                18Feb2000
2                17Oct1960       17Oct1960
```

I want to count how many distinct birthdays there are for each form. You can consider each row a subset of the form. In this example, there are 3 distinct birthdays for form 1, and 3 distinct birthdays for form 2.

I know the code to count the number of distinct entries per column is 
COUNT(DISTINCT ...), but sometimes the same birthday is located in multiple columns, so simply summing the distinct counts for each column does not work.

I want output to look like:

```
FORM_NUM      COUNT
1             3
2             3
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Edit: It works. Code goes something like this...

```html
SELECT FORM_NUM, COUNT(DOB) FROM  

(SELECT FORM_NUM, DOB_1 as DOB FROM table WHERE LEN(DOB_1) > 0
UNION
SELECT FORM_NUM, DOB_2 as DOB FROM table  WHERE LEN(DOB_2) > 0
UNION
SELECT FORM_NUM, DOB_3 as DOB FROM table WHERE LEN(DOB_3) > 0
UNION
SELECT FORM_NUM, DOB_4 as DOB FROM table WHERE LEN(DOB_4) > 0
UNION
SELECT FORM_NUM, DOB_5 as DOB FROM table WHERE LEN(DOB_5) > 0)TMP


GROUP BY FORM_NUM
```

Comment: The easiest way is to make one ordinary aggregate for each column and merge results in a single table/output. Maybe you can also do it using partition over and distinct

Comment: whenever you append "1", "2", "3" onto your column names you are setting yourself up for problems. case in point, this question is easily solved with a COUNT and a GROUP BY if you had the schema correct.  The simple way of just adding more columns ends up making other things harder.

Comment: You need to give an alias to the derived table. Try ending the parentheses with some name.

Comment: Thanks, just figured that out. I am getting results now, testing to make sure they are accurate

Comment: In addition to bad database design mentioned by @KM you shouldn't store dates as varchar either.

Comment: I didn't create the database but thanks for the tips - I will keep it in mind if I'm ever responsible for creating one in the future

Comment: @JamesZ, ha, that has to be the absolute worst possible way possible to store dates as strings! good luck trying to find dates less than or greater than these.  I bet the rest of the DB is a complete wreck.

Comment: @offcenter35, I feel your pain, I've had to work on some nasty databases created by very clueless people. good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like following:

```
select FORM_NUM, count(DOB) from (
   select FORM_NUM, DOB_1 as DOB from table where DOB_1 is not null
   union
   select FORM_NUM, DOB_2 as DOB from table where DOB_2 is not null
   union
   select FORM_NUM, DOB_3 as DOB from table where DOB_3 is not null
) TMP
GROUP BY FORM_NUM
```

This will select each field separately and union will remove duplicate values

Comment: Sadly it will throw an error. Try editing it a bit my friend.

Comment: Followed this, still some sort of syntax error..see edit in post

Comment: Not my day it seems, forgot to add the column name.

Comment: I'm new to SQL so just for learning purposes here's my explanation for the code, let me know if I'm wrong in anything:  This code creates a temporary table TMP with a column DOB. The number of rows in this column is equal to the number of unique DOB for that form, since the 'union' operator only adds distinct values. Then the count(DOB) simply returns the number of distinct DOB associated with that form.

Comment: @offcenter35 Not a temporary table.  The phrase "temporary table" has a specific meaning in SQL.  Technically, it's an **inline view**, which is simply a subquery in the FROM clause which is behaving like a table or view.  Otherwise you're correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT FORM_NUM, COUNT(DOB) COUNT FROM

(SELECT FORM_NUM, DOB_1 DOB FROM YOURTABLE
UNION
SELECT FORM_NUM, DOB_2 DOB FROM YOURTABLE
UNION
SELECT FORM_NUM, DOB_3 DOB  FROM YOURTABLE) A GROUP BY FORM_NUM
```

Comment: I believe this is the right track. I wrote code following this that is producing error messages, please see my edit in original post and advise

Comment: Try this code: SELECT FORM_NUM, COUNT(*) FROM  

    (SELECT FORM_NUM, DOB_1 FROM table WHERE LEN(DOB_1) > 0
    UNION
    SELECT FORM_NUM, DOB_2 FROM table  WHERE LEN(DOB_2) > 0
    UNION
    SELECT FORM_NUM, DOB_3 FROM table WHERE LEN(DOB_3) > 0
    UNION
    SELECT FORM_NUM, DOB_4 FROM table WHERE LEN(DOB_4) > 0
    UNION
    SELECT FORM_NUM, DOB_5 FROM table WHERE LEN(DOB_5) > 0)A

    GROUP BY FORM_NUM